# Terminal immediately closes itself after opening

Tags: command-line, gnome

Whenever I run Terminal or Ctrl-alt-T the terminal will open up for a split second and close itself. If I run gnome-terminal in X Term I get the same problem and the following message:

> (gnome-terminal:12319): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get: the format string may not contain '&' (key 'monospace-font-name' from schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface'). This call will probably stop working with a future version of git.

This happened after I changed the settings in the terminal, how do I fix it?

Comment: What setting did you exactly change (and into what?)

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the key mentioned in the error message now contains a '&'. To see what its value currently is, open a console terminal, as this won't suffer from this bug: press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>F2</kbd>...<kbd>F6</kbd>), login, and do:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name
```

To change it, do

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name 'Ubuntu Mono 13'
```

(or any other value you like).

You can also run Software Center or Synapsis and install `dconf-editor`. This gives you a GUI that will let you view and change the value of the key.

Comment: You might want to add he should install `dconf editor`, since the terminal is inaccessible (I guess `xterm` will be affected as well)

Comment: Ah. Hadn't thought of that... (although the OP could always have started one on CTRL+ALT+F1 ;-)